# Find the value of S/t

Tags: sequences-and-series

If $S=\Sigma _{k=1}^{\infty}1/k^2$ and $t=\Sigma^{\infty}_{k=1}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k^2}$
Then we have to find the value of S/t .

I thought about it a lot and I think it cannot be solved individually .

Can somebody provide me a hint .

Comment: $$t=S-2\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{1}{(2k)^2}=S-2\frac{S}{4}=\frac{S}{2}$$ hence $\frac{S}{t}=2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT:**

Note that we can write the series in terms of even and odd terms as

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k^2}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{(2k-1)^2}-\frac{1}{(2k)^2}\right)\tag1$$

and

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{(2k-1)^2}+\frac{1}{(2k)^2}\right)\tag2$$

What happens when you subtract the right-hand sides of $(1)$ and $(2)$?

Comment: Why we will add it , the question is asking in divide form

Comment: Upon subtracting what do you find?

Comment: Very nice approach

Comment: $S+t=    2 \sum_{k=1}^\infty (\frac{1}{(2k-1)^2}$

Comment: @RRL Thank you!  Much appreciated.

Comment: @Koolman Subtract the two.  What do you obtain?

Comment: @MarkViola i have edited my comment

Comment: Subtract them now.

Answer (score 3):

Note that
$$ S-2\frac{1}{4}S = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} - \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{2}{(2k)^2} = t, $$
since the even terms in the first sum are half the terms in the second sum, which gives the $(-1)^{n+1}$. The same trick works on $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{-s}$ for any $s$ for which the sum converges.